# Click on list jQuery in WATIR

Tags: jquery, watir

Trying to click on the item from a drop down list.

The HTML looks like below. It is embedded in a `span` and `href`.

```
 <BODY>
 <DIV id="main" class="iFrameClass ng-scope" ng-controller="QT" tool="" jQuery18103501579987610235="2">
 <DIV class="container-fluid"><DIV class="row-fluid">
 <DIV id="filtersAndGridContainer" class="span12" jQuery18103501579987610235="46">
 <DIV class="row-fluid"><DIV class="span9"><DIV class="btn-group">
 <UL class="dropdown-menu pull-right queryDropDown">
 <LI class="dropdownQuery ng-scope" ng-click="query" 
  ng-repeat="query in queryList | filter:  {favoriteQuery:false,publicQuery:true} |orderBy: 'displayName'"
  jQuery987610235="49">
  <A href="//link"   jQuery987610235="51"><SPAN class="ng-binding" jQuery987610235="50">Another</SPAN> 
 </A> 
</LI>

<LI class="dropdownQuer y ng-scope"
    ng-click="query"
    ng-repeat="query in queryList | filter:{favoriteQuery:false,publicQuery:true} |orderBy:'displayName'"
    jQuery579987610235="76">
  <A href="https://link/" jQuery579987610235="78">
    <SPAN class="ng-binding" jQuery579987610235="77">NeedToclickThis</SPAN>
  </A>
</LI>
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
link(:text=>"NeedToClickThis").flash
```

I also tried `xpath`:

```
li(:xpath => '//*[@id="filtersAndGridContainer"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[14]').flash
```

Both throw an unknown object error.
Error message:

`assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"],  (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)`

How do I click on the the link 'NeedToClickThis', which is embedded inside li and a elements.

Comment: The only input this question needs right now is _more_ from _you_. Add more detail and a better explanation of your problem as well as what you've tried

Comment: I agree with @Bojangles .. also the code you posted is malformed, with ending tags that have no start tag.. and your code is all on one line, not formatted for readability ...

Comment: Did you click on the button that makes the list of links visible?

Comment: Tried to update the question with more information. thanks.

Comment: Tried ie.div(:class=>"span9").div(:class=>"btn-group").link(:text => "NeedToClickThis").click as well. Error thrown : watir-classic-4.0.1/lib/wati
r-classic/element.rb:328:in `assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using {:t
ag_name=>["div"], :class=>"span9"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: Answering my own quetsion here..Here is what worked.ie.link(:index => 0).click

Answer (score 0):

Your link text is inside a span, which itself is inside that link, so trying to click that span text should click your link, which should be:

```
span(:text=>"NeedToClickThis").click
```